# Setting up Kong Ingress Controller on Kubernetes and receiving 502 Bad Gateway error for Ingress resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I used the [guide](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/install/kubernetes/helm-quickstart/) to set up Kong on my Kubernetes cluster running on Docker Desktop. I have a Kubernetes Service named `quick-links-service` which is exposed on port `3000`. I created an Ingress resource for this Service with the path value set to `/quick-links`, using the Kong Ingress controller. Additionally, I added a corresponding Service and Route for `quick-links-service` using the Kong Dashboard.

However, when I try to access `http://localhost/quick-links`, I receive a "502 - Bad Gateway" error message with the following response:

```
{
    "message": "An invalid response was received from the upstream server"
}
```

*quick-links-service.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: quick-links-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: quick-links
  ports:
    - name: quick-links
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
```

*quick-links-ingress.yaml*

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: quick-links-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /quick-links
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: quick-links-service
                port:
                  name: quick-links
```

[image: Kong Dashboard Service Image]
[image: Kong Dashboard Route Image]